# Active Directory Search from a String using Visual Studio

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio, active-directory

I have a Code that Returns the Email Address of a User from Active Directory using a Textbox. The Issue is, the User sometimes contains a space before the end of the parenthesis. e.g. Doe, John (Test ) or Doe, John (Test) which makes its difficult to return the value of the email address when the space is present or not. Is there a way to disregard the space when searching via Active Directory?

```
Private Sub txt_LMName_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
txt_LMName.TextChanged

    If txt_LMName.TextLength > 0 Then
        Dim rootEntry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://dc=*,dc=*,dc=*")

        Dim UserLMsearcher As New DirectorySearcher(rootEntry)
        UserLMsearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
        UserLMsearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(displayName=" & txt_LMName.Text & "))"

        Dim LMResults As SearchResultCollection
        LMResults = UserLMsearcher.FindAll()

        Dim LMResult As SearchResult

        For Each LMResult In LMResults

            txtTo.Text = LMResult.Properties("mail")(0)

        Next
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If there is space sometimes only within parentheses, then you can apply this logic: extract the string before parentheses + trim spaces in the string after parentheses and combine them. But, only attempt it when you're very sure that the format is not going to change!

Comment: Thank you for this! But I have tried trimming the spaces but was still unable to produce results. Do you have a sample Syntax for this?

Comment: Please share the code what you tried, and I'll help you with accomplishment of the result.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I'm having issues with the trimming spaces. The name of the User sometimes do have spaces before the end of the parenthesis. The value of the User comes from the textbox which is populated from active directory.